# How to create a bootable USB stick to flash a BIOS

Tags: boot, usb, bios

I want to upgrade the BIOS on an Intel motherboard using a program called `iflash2.exe`, provided by Intel, which runs only on MS-DOS.

I do not have Windows operating system, and I am trying to create a bootable USB stick that will contain MS-DOS, `iflash2.exe`, and related files.

I tried a program called UNetbootin, which created a bootable USB with FreeDOS, but I do not know how and where to add `iflash2.exe` and related files.

Can you tell me how I can do that?

Comment: I'm not sure how to interpret your question: Do you have a bootable USB stick now? Or do you have an image file only, and you want to know how to put it on the USB stick?

Comment: @elmicha I have a bootable USB stick that has an image file on it. I want to know how to put additional execulatble files on the USB stick.

Comment: When you plug the stick in, isn't it automatically opened, so you can drag and drop the files onto it?

Comment: @elmicha: A drive needs to be bootable in order to run any files at boot.  @sawa: did you try actually **writing** the image to the drive rather than leaving the image file just sitting on the drive?  As in actually extract the files in the image and write them to the disk?

Answer (score 13):

I have used the following technique to flash the BIOS on a HP N54L ProLiant MicroServer. I think it should work for other systems too that just need to run a command from MS-DOS after booting from a USB stick.

**I accept no responsibility if this goes wrong. If you don't understand what these instructions do then you probably shouldn't be attempting it.**

The following assumes that you have a set of files, or an archive file, that contains the new ROM and a script or executable that applies it. The BIOS might have come with an executable to create a USB from scratch; if you've got this far, you've probably tried running that already and failed. What you need to find are the ROM file and script or executable. In my case, the ROM file was called `O41072911.ROM` and the script was called `FLASH.BAT`.

### Create a bootable USB stick

Firstly, you need a USB stick formatted in the most basic way possible. This will erase all data on your USB stick, so back up anything important first!

1. Plug in your USB stick.
2. Select the *Format...* option from the launcher menu:

   [image: Format menu screenshot]
3. Select *Compatible with all systems (FAT)* as the type, give it a sensible name, and click *Format*:

   [image: Filesystem options screenshot]

Then you need to use UNetbootin to make the USB stick boot to an DOS prompt:

1. Install UNetbootin either using the Software Centre or from the command line using `sudo apt-get install unetbootin`.
2. Run UNetbootin. Select *FreeDOS* as the distribution and make sure the type is *USB Drive* and the correct drive is selected. Then click *OK*:

   [image: UNetbootin options screenshot]
3. When UNetbootin has finished, click *Exit*.

Now you have a USB stick that will boot to DOS.

### Add your BIOS files

Now you need to put your BIOS files onto the USB stick. As a general principle, you simply need to copy and paste the files onto the volume.

If they came in a self-extracting `.exe` file, you need to run it in order to extract the files. To do this, you'll need to:

1. Install Wine either using the Software Centre or from the command line using `sudo apt-get install wine`.
2. Find the `.exe` file that contains the BIOS files, right click it and run with Wine:

   [image: Open with Wine screenshot]
3. The exact details of what happens next will depend on your BIOS file, but extract the files to a directory somewhere you can remember.

Once you have your files extracted, copy them onto the USB stick. They can go in the root directory of the volume.

Take a look at the files; there is probably a file that contains the new ROM itself, and a `.bat` or `.exe` file that is used to apply it. If there's an `AUTOEXEC.BAT` file, take a look at it and note what command it runs to update the ROM.

### Flash

Now you're ready to flash your BIOS.

1. Eject your USB stick from the computer you created it on.
2. Insert it into the computer you want to flash and reboot.
3. Boot from the USB stick. You might need to adjust your boot order in the BIOS to achieve this.
4. You should see the blue FreeDOS boot loader appear with *Default* highlighted. Either wait 10 seconds or press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
5. At the FreeDOS menu, select the second option *FreeDOS Safe Mode (don't load any drivers)*:

[image]

6. You will end up at an `A:/>` prompt. Type `C:` then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to switch to the C drive.
7. Type `dir` then <kbd>Enter</kbd> and you should see all your files that you copied onto the USB stick.
8. Run the script or executable that you identified previously as the one to apply the BIOS update. In my case, I just had to type `FLASH` then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to run the `FLASH.BAT` file.
9. You should see the flash script applying your BIOS update. Do not power off or interrupt this process; wait until it has finished. It should return you to the `C:\>` prompt.
10. You can then remove your USB stick, and power cycle the computer.
11. Cross you fingers and boot using your new BIOS. Or cry if you just bricked your computer.

Comment: Note that the format option no longer appears in the launcher in currently supported versions of Ubuntu. Alo Archive manager is fully capable of extracting the files There's no need to use wine for that.

Comment: This is the only approach that worked for me on 16.04 that didn't require a Windows machine and Rufus.

Comment: Thanks this really helped me alot! FreeOS did the trick indeed.

Comment: I wasn't able to get a USB to boot using UNetbootin on Ubuntu 18.0.4 so I used https://www.balena.io/etcher/ instead. Downloaded FreeDOS 1.2 direct and installed its img file with Etcher and it booted right up. Also tried PuppyLinux for kicks and giggles and it booted right up as well. Don't forget to set USB as the first boot drive in the BIOS. The rest of the answer worked for me, with the slight change of from UNetbootin to Etcher. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I spent all morning struggling to find a way to flash the BIOS on my
Zotac motherboard. Unetbootin creates MS-DOS images that will boot, but
they cannot find the flash files (awdflash and N0422_ZA.bin in my case) on my
USB thumb drive.

What finally worked was creating an [Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com)
and booting FREEDOS (not MS-DOS) from that CD. Then the USB thumb drive
with my flashing files *was* visible, and the updating of the BIOS worked just fine.

Comment: This did not work for me. UBCD FreeDOS always crashed on loading various drivers.