# Re partion external hard drive

Tags: partitioning

Can anyone please tell me how to re partition an external hard drive without loosing the date on it. Thank you.

StrabagISS_ Krall, Hi, Recently had a power outage while transfering files to one of the drives. On reboot the whole system hung until I disconected the Hdd I was transfering files to. Ubuntu then booted normaly. On entering Disks utility the partition on the drive was not there, the partition on the second drive is still there ( /dev/sdc1). Disks can see the non partitioned drive, ( /dev/sdd unknown ) but it will not mount. I can reformat it, but there is so much valuable information I do not want to loose. I have attempted to rename the drive, and then create a partition with the ERASE turned off, but recieve the message warning all date will be lost. The original partition was NFTS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: Please add atleast some information to your question. Actual problem, partition layout, etc.

Comment: Melebius, sorry no It didn't, in this case Gparted has been unhelpful

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recovering broken or deleted NTFS partitions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/775579/recovering-broken-or-deleted-ntfs-partitions) and [NTFS partition can't be mounted in either Windows or Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/1207210)