# How to conduct data transfer from an Ubuntu machine that doesn't boot up?

Tags: 22.04, msi

I have an MSI Z16 with a dead motherboard so it doesn't boot. I will be getting a new laptop and I currently have a 5TB external drive. How can I conduct data transfer from this unbootable laptop to my external drive?

Comment: You will have to remove the hard drive from the unbootable machine.

Comment: .....and then???

Comment: Plug it into the new machine or a USB interface to the new machine.

Comment: How can I plug it in to the new machine?
I want to plug it into the USB interface.

Comment: Use a USB-to-hard-drive dock. If you edit your question and give more information about what you actually want to achieve (just get your data, clone the system or what), an answer can be written.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NTFS partition can't be mounted in either Windows or Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1207210/ntfs-partition-cant-be-mounted-in-either-windows-or-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I forgot to mention one option: if the new laptop supports the same NVMe SSD storage, you can very likely just move the NVMe drive from the old laptop into the new one.  You may still want an external enclosure (see below) in order to be able to use the new internal drive as additional external storage.
--
If this is an MSI Creator Z16, then your internal storage is an NVMe PCIe SSD.  MSI's page for this system states:
`SSD: Up to 2x NVMe PCIe Gen4 x 4 SSD`

https://ca.msi.com/Content-Creation/Creator-Z16-A11UX/Specification

As mentioned in the comments, you need to remove the storage from the dead laptop, and install it into an external NVMe case (an "enclosure", not a "dock") that connects via USB.  A web search for "external nvme usb" or similar will show you many options; choose one that matches your NVMe drive.

Then on a working machine, connect both your 5TB external drive, and the Z16's drive (which is now in the external NVMe enclosure).

Depending on your system settings and user account settings, you may now be able to see both the Z16's drive and your 5TB drive in your file manager, and copy files from one to the other.

You may have to perform the copy as the root user, depending on the file/directory permissions on the NVMe drive.

Also if your Z16 system was installed with encryption, or using the LVM storage management layer, you'll have to do a bit more configuration before being able to copy.

Let us know how far you get.